# OnClick event perform on runtime generated widgets

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, runtime

In my application i am displaying a TableLayout within an ScrollView at the runtime. This is all generating at runtime. I am creating this view from activity class, not from any xml. Now i want to perform an operation on the click of a row of this generated table to bring execution to display details of the content written in the row. Please help how we can perform operation on the click of a row of runtime generated table which is in Scroll View?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, However if it is what I think, have a look at view.setTag(), this will help you to add the reference to another view, or any object

So on click of this view, use (View)view.getTag() and change the visibility or do something with it.

Comment: thanks azlam, actually i just want to go into another page of application on the click of a widget added in view at runtime from activity.

Comment: You seem right azlam. The best way to identify the runtime generated view is to set a tag for it before adding it to parent view like:

Tabrow tabrow = new Tabrow(this);
tabrow.setTag(2);
tablayout.add(tabrow);